# How to upgrade bitcoind in docker?

Tags: bitcoind, core-lightning

I am running the docker version for c-lightning 0.7

On a raspberry I need to clone the blockchain, but it needs version 0.17.1

Looking at the docker-compose.yml file I see:

```
version: "3"
services:
  bitcoind:
    image: nicolasdorier/docker-bitcoin:0.16.3
    container_name: bitcoind
    ...
```

How can I upgrade to 0.17.1?

Answer (score 1):

Nicolas' [`docker-bitcoin`](https://hub.docker.com/r/nicolasdorier/docker-bitcoin/tags) image has `0.17.0` tag available, so changing that image to that version should just work:

```
version: "3"
services:
  bitcoind:
    image: nicolasdorier/docker-bitcoin:0.17.0
    container_name: bitcoind
    ...
```